# Query a join where a specific key value row does not exist

Tags: mysql

Trying to query the following
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6934c/1
So that I can get sum of all order_totals where an order is of price_group 1 AND does NOT have the promo row in the order_meta table.

Well aware this isn't the best database design, but I'll need to live with it for a bit longer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select sum(o.Order_total) as total
from orders o
inner join order_meta pm on pm.order_id = o.id
left join order_meta om on om.order_id = o.id and om.type = 'promo'
where pm.type = 'price_group'
and pm.value = 1
and om.Id is null
```

This should work because the first join + the where clause makes sure that the order has a price group meta record with the value of 1.  The second join + the null check in the where clause makes sure there is no record of type promo.

Comment: @vogomatix The pm is the first join of the order_meta table.  It is used to make sure the order is part of 'price_group'.

Comment: Yes I know - see the other answers. Yours fails to access pm.value and ensure it is 1, the others do. Also you don't explain your solution. In fact none of us do, which would be a good reason to downvote

Comment: @vogomatix - Ok, I totally missed the price_group = 1 part.  I also added a brief explanation.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

([**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6934c/51)):

```
SELECT SUM(order_total)
FROM orders AS o
  INNER JOIN order_meta AS om 
  ON o.id = om.order_id
WHERE om.type = 'price_group'
  AND om.value = 1
  AND o.id NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT oms.id 
    FROM order_meta AS oms 
    WHERE oms.type = 'promo'
  )
```

Comment: OP asked for **where an order is of price_group 1 AND does NOT have the promo row** order 1 has promo so should not come in result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(o.order_total) 
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN order_meta om ON o.id = om.order_id
LEFT JOIN order_meta om2 on o.id = om2.order_id AND om2.type = 'promo'
WHERE om.type = 'price_group' AND om.value = 1 AND om2.type IS NULL
```

Comment: Your example has an error in the syntax [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6934c/29)

Comment: Fixed that for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding you asked for the sum of orders that only have  price_group not the promo code try this one  using `NOT EXISTS` by selecting the order that promo code so it will not be included in the sum of orders

```
select *,SUM(order_total) from orders o
LEFT JOIN order_meta
om ON(o.id=om.order_id)    
WHERE om.type ='price_group' AND om.value =1 
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM order_meta 
WHERE `type` ='promo' AND
order_id= o.id
)
GROUP BY o.id
```

<kbd>[**See Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6934c/33)</kbd>

Here is the sum of all orders excluding the orders that have promo code

```
select *,SUM(order_total) from orders o
LEFT JOIN order_meta
om ON(o.id=om.order_id)
WHERE om.type ='price_group' AND om.value =1 
 AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM order_meta 
WHERE `type` ='promo' AND
order_id= o.id
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo All Orders**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6934c/43)</kbd>